# reloading a parent div without affecting the children divs

Tags: jquery

I have a chat like system in which the div containing the logged in friends is reloaded.
But the problem is, that when I reload this div. The divs inside this are reloaded and the chatboxes disappear. I have some code like this

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
$('div#div1').load('./1.php #div1');
}, 5000);
</script>
<div id="loggedinfriends">
Some friends 
<div id="friendchatbox" style="position:fixed;right:2px;bottom:o;height:400px;">
and the content goes here
</div>
```

i cannot separate the friendchatbox from the div1 because they are in  a single loop. and after clicking  the link from div1 the friendchatbox opens.
Is there any way to reload the div1 without affecting the friendbox.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reload an element, and exclude a child element from reloading.

Simply splitting the code will fix the problem. You can then simply refresh `$('#loggedinfriends')`

```
<div>
  <div id="loggedinfriends">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="friendchatbox">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Well, it is not completely true. You can obviously get the contents of a child element, remember that, refresh `div1`, then restore the contents of that child element. There should however not be any reason to do that.